# Passing props to child component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, constructor, components

I can't seem to figure out how to log my props from my App component to my child TotalBox component. It keeps returning as an empty object. Does anyone know how to do this successfully?

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
  }

  handler() {
    this.setState({
      value: 0
    })
  }

  render() {

  return (
  <Wrapper>
    <Grid>
      <Row>
        <CostBox/>
        <Input/>
        <TotalBox {...this.props}/>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  </Wrapper>
)
  }
}
```

**totalBox.js**.

```
class TotalBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props); // Object {}
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Col md={3}>
        <RightBox>
          <TotalCostHeader>TOTAL COST</TotalCostHeader>
          <TotalCostLabel>{this.state.value}</TotalCostLabel>
        </RightBox>
      </Col>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the props of your App component?

Comment: What is `this.props` in the App component?

Comment: I want to pass the numeric value of `value` so I can manipulate it in the child component and others

Comment: So you have `this.props.value` at some point in the App component? Edit: it seems to me you have only set `this.state.value`

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing by setting the state of `value`.

Comment: If that is the case, you could just pass in `<TotalBox value={this.state.value}/>`

Comment: When I do that I get an error saying 'A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development'

Comment: You need to set it first. Looking at your code you only set your state in the `handler()` function. You either need a placeholder or call it before passing in to props (Will write a full answer with the code and everything)

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually intend to pass the `this.props`, or did you mean to pass `this.state`? From the code, it seems that you want to pass `this.state`, which has a `value` property and use the passed `value` property. You're also missing initialization of `this.state` inside the `App` component constructor:

```
this.state = {
  value: 0,
}
```

Also, keep in mind that the constructor will only be called once when the component is created before it's first rendered. And later updates to the passed props will not be caught inside the `constructor`. If you want to catch later updates, you'll have to use the [`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) component lifecycle method.

I would also suggest you refrain from using `{...this.props}` syntax and rather use explicit `value={this.props.value}` if you're expecting a `value` property to be passed. The `{...this.props}` can seem like a clean solution, but it's less readable because it doesn't provide the context of what exactly you're passing to the component. This syntax can be useful, but the cases are rare. Usually, it's when it's a generic higher-order component which encloses another component and you want to pass the props to the enclosed component.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason,you need send props from parent to child like following:

```
 <TotalBox value={this.state.value}/>
```

Comment: If the `this.props` contains the key `value`, what OP has done with `{...this.props}` is shorthand for what you're suggesting. If the `this.props` doesn't contain a value for the `value` key, this will still not work.

Comment: sorry, I fixed it.
You need to define each props separately and send it to the child from parent.

Comment: `<TotalBox {...this.props}/>` is not correct approach, because `this.props` is related to the `App.js` component not the `TotalBox.js` .

Comment: what are you talking about? What you're proposing above compiles to `React.createElement(TotalBox, {value: this.props.value});` (before you've fixed the `props` -> `state`, doesn't matter for this example). What the OP is doing by `<TotalBox {...this.props} />` compiles to `React.createElement(TotalBox, this.props);` If the `this.props.value` exists, and for the sake of argument, let's assume that it does, how are these two code snippets different? The passed props compile to an object with corresponding keys, if the `{...obj}` has same keys, it's the same code. No magic here.

Comment: For calling the `TotalBox.js` component, if instead of using `<TotalBox value={this.state.value}/>` we use <TotalBox value={this.props.value}/>, we are sending the `App.js`'s `props` to the `TotalBox.js` which is not our goal. We should define all props one by one and then send them to the 'TotalBox.js' component. Then inside the `TotalBox.js` component we'll access to all `props` using `...this.props`.

Comment: You're arguing a different argument here. I've already pointed out that and you've fixed it. I've also pointed out that in my answer. It's also mentioned in the answer by @theJuls. The problem is resolved, the OP probably wants to use `this.state`, not `this.props`. But using `<TotalBox value={this.state.value} />` or `<TotalBox {...this.state} />` doesn't really matter, the result will be the same. It's just personal preference and in my opinion, it's more readable to use the first one with explicit props declarations, as I've also mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, the first thing you are doing wrong is in the `App` component appropriately passing down `value` as props to TotalBox. You do have a `this.state.value` which is done in your `handler()` function.

At first glance, the solution would be to simply set the `<TotalBox value={this.state.value}/>`

However now we have the problem that your state has not been set, since the `handler()` function hasn't been called yet (which is the only place you actually set the state according to your code).

If you are expecting it to be called later, you do need to set some sort of placeholder value to `this.state.value` in the App component. Which could look something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
    this.state = {value: 0} // placeholder value set here
  }

  handler() {
    this.setState({
      value: 0
    })
  }

  render() {

  return (
  <Wrapper>
    <Grid>
      <Row>
        <CostBox/>
        <Input/>
        <TotalBox value={this.state.value}/>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  </Wrapper>
)
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply not render the `TotalBox` component if the state or state.value has not been set. So something like this in the App component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
    this.state = {} // don't forget to declare the state object itself
  }

  handler() {
    this.setState({
      value: 0
    })
  }

    render() {
        const totalBox = this.state.value ? <TotalBox value={this.state.value}/> : null
          return (
          <Wrapper>
            <Grid>
              <Row>
                <CostBox/>
                <Input/>
                {totalBox}
              </Row>
            </Grid>
          </Wrapper>
        )
          }
}
```

Edit: you mentioned you want to update the parent's state through the child component. Here the code of how to do that using the `handler` function:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
  }

  handler() {
    this.setState({
      value: 0
    })
  }

  render() {

  return (
  <Wrapper>
    <Grid>
      <Row>
        <CostBox/>
        <Input/>
        <TotalBox value={this.state.value} handler={this.handler.bind(this)}/>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  </Wrapper>
)
  }
}

class TotalBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props); // Object {}
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value
    }
  }

 // Im using handler as a name for this function just as an example
 // this would be whatever you call as a function to update the state of
 // the parent component.
 handler () {
   // this is the function from your parent component
   // being executed to update its state
   this.props.handler()
 }  

  render() {
    return (
      <Col md={3}>
        <RightBox>
          <TotalCostHeader>TOTAL COST</TotalCostHeader>
          <TotalCostLabel>{this.state.value}</TotalCostLabel>
        </RightBox>
      </Col>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Using the wording " you are not setting `this.props.value`" can be confusing. You can't actually set the `this.props` values of the component, it doesn't behave as one might expect. You are correct by mentioning that the OP probably wants to use a value from `this.state`, but the statement before can be misleading.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still getting an empty object in the first solution and the page doesn't render in the second.

Comment: For the first solution I screwed up the render code (fixed it now). Are you passing `value={this.state.value} for it?

Comment: I seem to have gotten that working, now is there a way that once that value is modified in a child component that I can have that register in the parent component and then use that updated value in my child component?

Comment: As for the second solution, it is possibly because `totalBox` is going to null. It would only work if you set `this.state.value` before you expect to render the `TotalBox` component. In the code you gave at no point is `this.state.value` actually set.

Comment: There is a way, yes. You need to create a function in the parent component which modified its state. That function needs to be passed down to the child via props and executed whenever it is time to update the state.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I've been trying to do this and can't seem to understand how it works. How would that kind of callback work?

Comment: Added an edit to my answer with an example of how you do that.